# `tcsh` repeat with subshell

Tags: shell-script, tcsh

I'm trying to figure out how to repeat a complex command inside a repeat in `tcsh`, like so

```
repeat 9999 (curl http://localhost:80/index.php; echo)
```

I am using a subshell here instead of `{` and `}` because, according to http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells, tcsh doesn't have this feature.

However, I get the following unexpected error from the previous construct.

```
Badly placed ()'s
```

So, how do you repeat a complex command with `tcsh`?

There are a few old rants out there about weird inconsistencies of `csh` and, by extension, `tcsh`, e.g. this one http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt . So I'm not sure what to think of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `tcsh(1)`:

```
repeat count command
    The  specified  command,  which is subject to the same restric‐
    tions as the command in the one line  if  statement  above,  is
    executed  count  times. [..]
```

And from the `if` documentation:

```
if (expr) command
    [..]
    command must  be  a  simple  command,  not  an alias,  a  pipeline,  a
    command list or a parenthesized command list, but it  may  have
    arguments. [..]
```

So it looks like this is not something you can do.

To work around it you can use a simple wrapper script.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use "eval" for that, e.g.:

```
repeat 7 eval "cmd1;cmd2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround would be to instead use ZSH.

```
% repeat 3 (echo hi; echo there)
hi
there
hi
there
hi
there
%
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `repeat` is a builtin command but not part of the syntax, you cannot use ()s in the argument list easily.

Even with the `Bourne Shell` that is less limited than `tcsh`

```
repeat -c 3 (echo a)
```

will not work.

What works is:

```
(repeat -c 10 echo a)
```

as this runs the whole command in a subshell. But even:

```
(repeat -c 3 echo a; echo b)
```

will repeat the `echo a` three times but just call `echo b` once..

However:

```
repeat -c 3 "echo a"
```

is recommended in case you like to repeat more than a simple command with the `repeat` builtin. This works even for less simple commands because `repeat` behaves similar to `eval`.

Comment: What shell are you using that accepts `repeat -c 3 "echo a"`? I've tested it with `bash`, `dash`, and `mksh`. Are you talking about defining a `repeat` function yourself in a Bourne-compatible shell?

Comment: I am talking about the recent BourneShell, see: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html The `repeat` command that implements the `-c` option first appeared in 1984 in my `bsh`, based on a similar external `UNOS` command from 1980 (UNOS was the first UNIX clone) . Repeat and other features from `bsh`have been added to the `Bourne Shell` aprox. 4 years ago.